# Xcode 4.3 not presenting Autoresizing panel in Size Inspector

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 4.3 I'm not seeing the "Autoresizing" panel (with the red crosshair things) in the Attributes Size Inspector.

What I see instead are two panels, one titled "**Content Hugging Priority**" and the other
titled "**Content Compression Resistance Priority**".

Other than baffling me, they seem to
no effect on anything if I adjust their settings.

In projects started before 4.3 installation I still get the Autoresizing red line things,
but for 4.3 created projects I am currently unable to control the location and size behavior of view controls.

Comment: This is for an OS X project, right?

Answer (score 110):

For Xcode 4.3 auto layout is enabled by default. To disable deselect the "use auto layout" option in the file inspector tab.

[image: file inspector tab]

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Chapters/xcode_4_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016147-SW2

Comment: @PZX OK. If this answers your question, please check it as the answer.

Comment: It is not obvious from the screenshot where this checkbox is (bad cropping). I have found it in File Inspector tab (the first one) on the right panel of Interface Builder. It doesn't matter what element you have selected.

Comment: OK, the REALLY CRUMMY thing is, you have to set this on EACH of your NIB files.  Can't you set that as a global default?

Answer (score 23):

In Xcode 4.5 you need to go to file inspector to uncheck the Use Autolayout, then go back to Size inspector, the good old Autosizing is back where it was. :) 
Don't you just hate that when then change things like that behind your back, precisely what Microsoft would do!

Comment: The file inspector is the first top level button in the right hand Utilities pane. The icon is shaped kind of like an SD card.