# The Autosizing property setting for NSView is missing

Tags: xcode, nsview, autoresize

I ran into this really frustrating issue today.

I want to set my view to be autosizing like this:

[image]

But all I find in my xcode settings for an NSView is like this:

[image]

The two screenshots are taken from two different projects with the same xcode 4.3.2. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.3 not presenting Autoresizing panel in Size Inspector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370072/xcode-4-3-not-presenting-autoresizing-panel-in-size-inspector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaid's solution works. but i think it's bug because the auto sizing tool will apear about half a second when switching to another inspector.

[Xcode 4 interface-builder problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631319/xcode-4-interface-builder-problems/12880181#12880181)

Answer (score 12):

Starting in Xcode 4.3 the xib files for Cocoa projects have auto layout turned on initially. When a xib file uses auto layout, there is no Autosizing section in the size inspector.

If you want to turn off auto layout, open the file inspector and deselect the Use Auto Layout checkbox.
[image]