# Xcode 4 interface-builder problems

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder

I have several problems with the interface builder in Xcode 4.
I am using Xcode 4.5 but the problems started even before I updated it.

My first problem is that if I edit a field (e.g. a text field from not editable to editable) it sometimes disappears. Or other fields change their position.

My second problem which is probably related to the first one is that the size inspector looks strange and when I switch do a different inspector the size inspector I'm used to appears for half a second before the new inspector appears. I have two screen shots:

strange size inspector:

[image: strange size inspector]

and the one during the switch between the inspectors:

[image: size inspector during the switch]

A possibly connected problem is that if I try to automatically create outlets by "ctrl" drag to the .h file it only creates the @property but not the @synthesize. And when I started with that project it did both.

Another problem is that if I reposition objects they are still at the old position when I build it. But I think thats a different kind of problem since I'm able to resolve that by restarting Xcode.

Besides that it is really slow to work with the interface builder in xcode 4 but as far as I read thats a general thing.

I know that these are several questions but I think they might be connected, thats why I asked them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return to your old style Size inspector, just turn off **"Use Autolayout"** in the file inspector of the XIB.