# UIWebView landscape rotation does not fill view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

I am having an issue with my UIWebView. When the view loads it loads in either orientation fine, fills the whole page perfectly etc.

However say if I load it in portrait then rotate the device the webview does not fill all the way across to the right hand side and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

This is my view did load method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib

    if  ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){

        self.measurementsWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367);

    }else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

        self.measurementsWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 218);
    }

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"measurements" ofType:@"png"];
    [measurementsWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];
    measurementsWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

}
```

If i look in interface builder I am trying to find the panel that allows me to set expanding width or what ever you call it, but all I can see is this.

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Instead of setting the frame manually, you could also set the auto-resizing masks as:

`measurementsWebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

which will resize the webView in case you have no other elements on the screen (which, I take it, you don't have, from the values you've used when resizing `measurementsWebView`). Or, straight from the nib as shown in the following image:

[image: auto-resize from nib]

The masks can be set by clicking on the red bars in the box called **Autosizing** towards the bottom left.

Answer (score 3):

`viewDidLoad` is run once - when the view loads.

If you want to manually adjust the frame when rotation occurs, add code to to resize it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which is called whenever the view rotates.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.measurementsWebView.frame = self.view.bounds;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder, the drop-down menu where it says 'Layout Rectangle', click it and select 'Frame Rectangle'.

Alternatively you could override the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` method in your view controller and set the co-ordinates/size manually as you have done in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: weird, even when I do that its not changing the appearance of the menu... I think maybe I need to re-install xcode. I will try shouldAutototateToInterfaceOrientation now.. however will that change the size of the UIView Frame to fit the horizontal view.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` method. In a similar way to how you have checked for the orientation in your `viewDidLoad` method, you do the same here and adjust the view's frame.

Comment: For your problem with the interface builder, I recommend you read this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370072/xcode-4-3-not-presenting-autoresizing-panel-in-size-inspector)