# Can't detect orientation of device at launching app to create UIWebView with correct size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

If I started my app I want to know the orientation of my device.
In my main `view controller` I have a `UIWebView` which I added programmatically to the main `view controller`.

I tested it with `(int)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` but I only get the number 1. No matter if my device is in portrait or in landscape.

I want to set the size of my `UIWebView` but if I not know the orientation how can I set the size of it?

```
2016-01-21 17:21:45.387 iPhoneApp[1026:151720] 0) Orientation: 1
2016-01-21 17:21:45.388 iPhoneApp[1026:151720] 0) Orientation: 0
2016-01-21 17:21:45.393 iPhoneApp[1026:151720] 1) Orientation: 1
2016-01-21 17:21:45.393 iPhoneApp[1026:151720] 1) Orientation: 0
2016-01-21 17:21:45.406 iPhoneApp[1026:151720] 2) Orientation: 1
2016-01-21 17:21:45.406 iPhoneApp[1026:151720] 2) Orientation: 1
2016-01-21 17:21:45.417 iPhoneApp[1026:151720] 3) Orientation: 1
2016-01-21 17:21:45.417 iPhoneApp[1026:151720] 3) Orientation: 1
```

0 is in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

1 is in `viewDidLoad`

2 is in `viewDidAppear`

3 is in my method where I create my `UIWebView`

```
NSLog(@"3) Orientation: %d", (int)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);
NSLog(@"3) Orientation: %d", (int)[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
```

That's always the order of my log.

The method where I created my `UIWebView` looks like

```
-(void)createWebView {
    //NSLog(@"createWebView");
    //NSLog(@"orientation: %d", [[self orientNr] intValue]);
    [self destroyWebView];
    NSLog(@"3) Orientation: %d", (int)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);
    NSLog(@"3) Orientation: %d", (int)[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
    if( ([self firstLoad] && [[self orientNr] isEqualToNumber:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:2]]) ||
        ([self firstLoad] && [[self orientNr] isEqualToNumber:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1]] && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])))
        [self setWebView:[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)]];
    else
        [self setWebView:[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self view] addSubview:[self webView]];
    });
    [[self webView] setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [[self webView] setDelegate:self];
    [[self webView] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [[self view] setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    //NSLog(@"iPhoneApp: %@", [self webView]);
}
```

The variable `firstLoad` checks if the app is started yet. `orientNr` is a number to rotate the app to the given orientation I want, not important for the solution (1 is device and 2 is landscape). `webView` is of type `UIWebView`.

So If I started the app and my device in portrait I want to create the `webView` with 320 width and 568 height. If it's at startup in landscape I want create the `webView` with 568 width and 320 height.

My problem is to detect the orientation of my device at startup. I also searched and found some threads like ([Get launch orientation of iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402401/get-launch-orientation-of-ipad-app) or [iOS: Device orientation on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888016/ios-device-orientation-on-load)) but it doesn't solved my problem

## EDIT:

It only happens if I have my device on landscape or the `UIWebView` should start in landscape at launching the app

## EDIT 2:

Problem solved. I only added

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [[self webView] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
}
```

and my `UIWebView` has always the same size like my `UIView`. In landscape orientation too.
The answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24398249/5629933) solved my problem. I'm new to Objective-C but does is make sense although I set the size of my `UIWebView` to the same like my `UIView` when I create it?

Comment: Some of what you are doing is way too early, which is why you get useless results. But you shouldn't need to know the orientation of the device at all. Position your web view using auto layout. That way, no matter what happens, it will be in the right position.

Comment: Ah okay I understand but the size is not set correctly. If you can see in my method where I create my `web view` the size of it is always 320 width and 568 height. Imagine if the orientation is set to landscape for this view my `web view` is in correct orientation but the size doesn't fit the whole screen. The same problem if my device is in landscape mode only the size of my website doesn't fit the whole screen because the width of my `UIView` is always 320 width and 568 height @matt. How I can solve it?

Comment: That screenshot makes no sense. What part of that is `self.view`? What part of that is supposed to be the web view? And what part is the page loaded into the web view?

Comment: @rmaddy I added another screenshot. My `web view` is on the left side with the content (the sentence). It should filled the whole screenshot and not only the half

Comment: That screen shot is even worse. It's just white. How can you tell whether the web view is really filling `self.view` or not? Set `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];`. Run your app. Do you see any green? If not, then the web view is filling `self.view`.

Comment: It was my fault, sry. I filled the `UIView` green (`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]`). Now we see that the size of my `UIWebView` doesn't fill my `self.view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the code in your `createWebView` method isn't needed. The big thing is to set the `autoresizingMask` before adding the web view.

```
-(void)createWebView {
    //NSLog(@"createWebView");
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
}
```

Comment: I thought so too but if the website is configured to landscape when I started my app it doesn't fit my whole screen. It only has a size of 320 width and 568 height. The website has the correct orientation but the size of my `web view` is not correct. It only has the half size of landscape @rmaddy

Comment: I'm confused. Is your issue that the size of the web view isn't filling `self.view` or is the problem that the loaded website isn't filling the web view properly?

Comment: My issue is that my `web view` isn't filling my `self.view`

Comment: I do all of my apps strictly in code just like posted in my answer. Code like that should ensure that the web view will fill `self.view` no matter how the size of `self.view` changes. How do you know the web view isn't filling `self.view`?

Comment: I edited my post. It looks like this image. Adopted it isn't that problem why is it not fullscreen?

Comment: Thx helped me a lot with your questions and advices.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire `createWebView` approach is ill-advised. You should not be concerned with orientation at all. Just add your web view to `self.view` and position it using auto layout. That way, when layout finishes, it will be in the right position / size regardless of orientation or anything else that may happen to `self.view`.