# Xcode Create a working app for iOS 5.1 with xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5.1, xcode4.6, ios6.1

i can run my app on my 6.1 iOS but can't with 5.1
i have the iOS Deployment Target set to 5.1 on both Project and Target
when i run the simulation for 5.1 it works fine but when i try it on my iPhone it crash's
i committed out all my code thinking that was the problem but the same thing keeps happening

XIB and auto-layout is not enabled

The iPhone simulation works with no errors
I tried to create a new project and have only a label and i still get the same out come

can some one send a link to a single view project that works with 5.1, the program could be blank i just want to compare to mine to see what is different/ wrong.

Comment: Do you have a XIB or storyboard with auto-layout enabled?

Comment: XIB and it is auto-layout is not enabled

Comment: You should try debugging it or getting the crash log to see what is happening. When you have more information put that information in your question.

Comment: if i have it enabled i get ViewController.xib:
 error: Illegal Configuration: Auto Layout on iOS Versions prior to 6.0

Comment: how do i get the crash log from my iphone?

Comment: I can't plug the device in since i don't sign because my device is jail-broken and I am not uploading it to the app store

Comment: I don't have experience with jail-breaking, but I think it should still be possible to get the log using Xcode organizer even if your device is jail-broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might be trying to use an API that is specific to iOS6 (UICollectionView or something similar).

You need to plug the device in and run it and see what the console indicates is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have Auto Layout turned on for `ViewController.xib`. There are two ways to work around this. Either disable Auto Layout on that xib:

1) [Xcode 4.3 not presenting Autoresizing panel in Size Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370072/xcode-4-3-not-presenting-autoresizing-panel-in-size-inspector/9370105#9370105)

Or use one of many methods to enable auto layout while remaining backwards compatible:

2) [Enabling auto layout in iOS 6 while remaining backwards compatible with iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411980/enabling-auto-layout-in-ios-6-while-remaining-backwards-compatible-with-ios-5)