# Xcode: Autosizing preview window missing

Tags: xcode4.6, utilities

I am learning iOS and using Apress - Beggining iOS 5 development book. The book says there is a window to preview UI elements's autosizing behaviour in size inspector as:
[image]

but I can not see such a window. After searching in Xcode windows I realized that that windows actually appearing in a very short time period while switching size inspector to any other section in utilities tab. How can I make it constanly appear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer here
[Xcode 4.3 not presenting Autoresizing panel in Size Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370072/xcode-4-3-not-presenting-autoresizing-panel-in-size-inspector) Just uncheck "Use Auto Layout" option on file inspector tab:
[image]

Comment: This did the trick (it's in the File Inspector, first panel), although probably using auto layout is less work.

Answer (score 0):

While you are editing XIB or storyboard file. You can see "Size Inspector" tab panel at right menu. It has a ruler icon.

But the view -that you want to set it's layout- must be selected. At this sample on screenshot, a Label (text:social) is selected.

[image]

Comment: im unable to set height

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial can help to your problem.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2012/12/10/tutorial-ios-6-auto-layout-versus-springs-and-struts.aspx

Comment: Geç kaldın Erdi :) Benim cevabım daha açıklayıcı, sadece al buraya bak tipi cevaplar pek tutmaz ufaktan açıklama gerektirir.

Comment: Biliyorum. O autolayout başa bela. Benim de baya başımı ağrıtmıştı. Ufak bi not autolayout enable olunca ios 5 ve daha önceki cihazlarda uygulama patlar. Bu arada yeni işin hayırlı olsun :)

Comment: şaşırdım birden arkadaşlar :D googleda bu sayfayı görüntülerken  description kısmında Türkçe yazıyor. şaşırdım ve dedim ki translate mi oluyor sayfa  ki o anda muhabbeti gördüm  :D