# Custom UIView doesn't look as expected

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I would like to create a custom UIView so I could use it among a few UIViewControllers.

I created a xib file that looks like this:

[image]

The Above image has UIView, and inside 3 UIButtons

1. I created TopBar : UIView
2. I set the view size to freeform and the status bar to no.
3. I set the File's Owner class to TopBar
4. I dragged the UIView (which includes the 3 UIButtons) and called it contentView
5. I added in TabBar.m the method:

---

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TopBar" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview: _contentView];
}
```

---

6. I added to my UIViewController via storyboard the UIView and set its class to TopBar and its size to the UIView size in the xib

However, the result looks like this:

Why? What is wrong? (as you can see the buttons are extremely big and have spaces between them). I am supporting only Ios6 and above

[image]

Comment: All buttons have the same autosizing properties in the xib file ?

Comment: Where can I check it?

Comment: Open "utilities" tab of Xib file  (the right panel of XCode), select the tab "Size  inspector" and check if all buttons are docking top and left

Comment: @tdelepine can you please explain more how can I check the docking issue?

Comment: in This tab http://www.techotopia.com/images/f/f5/Ipad_xcode_size_inspector.jpg you can define how the UIView can be deformed, the docking is a fix point of UIView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that auto-layout was checked in the xib file of TabBar.

I deselected it and now it displayed it property

If anyone needs, [this shows how to deselect it in xcode 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370072/xcode-4-3-not-presenting-autoresizing-panel-in-size-inspector)